# How to lock Ubuntu home screen as Windows (WIN-L)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-10.10

How to lock Ubuntu home screen as Windows i.e., <kbd>WIN</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: I'm new to ubuntu... bear with me plz ;) It's a nice world tho!!!

Comment: if you're new to ubuntu, you might want to bookmark this site: askubuntu.com . 
It's basically a superuser for ubuntu.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

System -> Preferences -> Keybord Shortcuts.

Select Lock Screen and type <kbd>Win</kbd>+l

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 on a lenovo Z61p; I can change the shortcut to <kbd>Win+l</kbd>, it gets recorded as <kbd>Super+l</kbd>. However it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, if you want `win+L` *in addition* (rather than replacing) the default, you can set it up as a custom shortcut to execute `gnome-screensaver-command -l`

Answer (score 7):

Try `Ctrl+Alt+L`

Comment: Yes, that's the default shortcut. You can change it as described in my post though.

Comment: Actually, for someone used to `Win + L` your solution is better. +1

Comment: Both answers are good for me. The only thing is that I wanted Win-L since I'm brain-MS-washed.